# Emacs backspace at beginning of tabbed line similar to intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, emacs, backspace

In intellij, when you're at a tab indent of let's say 4, at the beginning of a new line, and you press backspace, it backspaces through all of the preceding whitespace and goes to the tab indent of 4 at the previous line.

In emacs, in the same situation, it backspace through a single space.

How do I make emacs behave like intelij's backspace system? Is there a plugin for this?

Here's an example of what happens when you hit backspace in intelij:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What should it do if there is text on the preceding line?  Back to the end of the text on the previous line or back to the beginning of the current line?  Also, what is the output of `C-h k Backspace`?

Comment: You shouldn't make Emacs too much like something else — just learn to do it the best way in the Emacs "language" and concentrate on more important things, otherwise you might be losing out on something else thanks to your special-case customisations.

Comment: If there is text on the preceding line, it should backspace to the end of the text on the preceding line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is close to what you want:

```
(defun my-backspace ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((end (save-excursion
                (end-of-line)
                (point)))
         (beginning (save-excursion
                      (beginning-of-line)
                      (point))))
    (if (string-match "^[ \t]*$" (buffer-substring beginning end))
        (progn
          (beginning-of-line)
          (kill-line)
          (previous-line)
          (indent-for-tab-command)
          (end-of-line))
      (c-electric-backspace))))

 (define-key c-mode-map (kbd "DEL") 'my-backspace)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, except that c-electric-backspace is not a function; I then changed c-electric-backspace to (delete-backward-char 1). Now everything is behaving as expected, except that when I go to open file (ctrl+o in ergoemacs), the backspace key doesn't do anything. Any idea on how to fix that?